# Drupal 7 and Commerce GoCardless Module - Library not loaded error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, payment-gateway, commerce, gocardless

I'm having trouble getting the GoCardless interface working. I've downloaded the GoCardless PHP library zip file from github. However, I'm unsure where to save it, and what to name the library. The documentation does not help.
When I try to pay with the "Direct Debit" option, I get a "GoCardless Library not loaded" error.

I'm using Drupal 7.37 and Commerce GoCardless 7.x-1.x-dev

I have a client waiting for their new website to go live, but cannot without the GoCardless payment working, so a speedy response would be appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use GitHub to download this library instead, and that seems to work.

In case you want to download the library via the zip option:

- Download the zip file to a local folder
- Unzip the file. It will create a folder called "gocardless-php-master"
- Rename the folder to "gocardless-php"
- Move the folder into your sites/all/libraries folder

Thanks to Pedro Cambra for suggesting I have a closer look at GitHub!